# How to speed up performance of a loop in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just wondering if there is any way to boost speed of my loop, or suggestions for best practice, cause I feel it looks so bad.

Here is the code:

```
for (index, _) in filteredArray.enumerate() {
    if index == 0 || index % 4 == 0 {
        let mediaItem = Item()
        mediaItem.id = filteredArray[index + 3]
        let photoURL = NSURL(string: filteredArray[index + 1])
        guard let url = photoURL else {  return  }
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        let finishImage = UIImage(data: data!)
        mediaItem.Photo = finishImage
        mediaItem.orderCount = filteredArray[index + 2]
        mediaItem.UUId = filteredArray[index]
        self.dataSourceItems.insert(mediaItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that this line: `let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)` takes the most time since network request is slow. Have you run the code through Instruments to find where's the bottleneck?

Comment: `NSData(contentsOfURL: url)` is synchronous, that's what's slowing down your loop. You may be interested in async web calls...

Comment: I see that you use  `if index == 0 || index % 4 == 0` but 0 % 4 = 0, so, except if I'm wrong, you could simply replace your condition by `if index % 4 == 0`.

Comment: @Larme Tnx Larme!

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise the index variable is dynamic so it could be any number

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem but a Code Review request. It would be better on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ДімаКомар It shouldnt change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `dispatch_apply`. Something like that:

```
let iterationsCount = filteredArray.count / 4
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

dispatch_apply(iterationsCount, queue) { i in
    let index = i * 4
    let mediaItem = Item()
    mediaItem.id = filteredArray[index + 3]
    let photoURL = NSURL(string: filteredArray[index + 1])
    guard let url = photoURL else {  return  }
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    let finishImage = UIImage(data: data!)
    mediaItem.Photo = finishImage
    mediaItem.orderCount = filteredArray[index + 2]
    mediaItem.UUId = filteredArray[index]
    self.dataSourceItems.insert(mediaItem)
}
```

Notice that, depending on your situation, you may need to 1. use `self` inside closure, if you accessing properties; 2. add some locks if you write to shared memory.